# Bugs while loading from text file

Tags: c++, text, vector, load, sdl

I'm currently maing a RTS game and I'm loading units from txt files int this way:

> 1 1 700 200 10
>
> /unit type/ /player/ /x co-ord/ /y co-ord/ /health/

I'm using a vector of settler(only unit I currently have) OBJECTS(not pointers) to keep all units

When I load the units and I try to draw them on the screen they just aren't there. I made a few tests and it occures that the vector "settlers" is empty even after I load from the txt file

The code of main.cpp:

```
vector<Settler> settlers;
...
void load_units(string filename)
{
settlers.clear();

ifstream unit_file(filename.c_str());
string line;
vector<vector<int> > ww;

while(unit_file.eof())
{
    while(getline(unit_file, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        int i;
        vector<int> w;
        while( ss >> i )
        {
            w.push_back(i);
        }
        ww.push_back(w);
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < ww.size(); i++)
{

    int type = ww[i][0];
    int player = ww[i][1];
    int x = ww[i][2];
    int y = ww[i][3];
    int hp = ww[i][4];

    if(type == 1)//settler
    {
        Settler settler(x, y, hp, player);
        settlers.push_back(settler);
    }
}
unit_file.close();}


...



void init() {
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

TTF_Init();

Mix_OpenAudio( 22050, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096 );

SDL_WM_SetIcon(IMG_Load("icon.png"), NULL);

screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(1600, 900, 32, SDL_FULLSCREEN);

map = IMG_Load("tlo.png");

bar = IMG_Load("bar.png");

pause_menu = IMG_Load("menu.png");

save_game_menu = IMG_Load("save_game_menu.png");

save_prompt = IMG_Load("saved_prompt.png");

load_game_menu = IMG_Load("load_game_menu.png");

load_prompt = IMG_Load("loaded_prompt.png");

intro_control = true;
menu = true;
running = false;
paused = false;
saving = false;
loading = false;

mapX = 0;
mapY = 0;

Xoffset = 0;
Yoffset = 0;

load_map("mapa1.txt");
load_units("units1.txt");

for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{
    string file_frame;

    stringstream ss;
    ss << i + 1;

    if(i < 9)
    {
        file_frame = ("intro/000");
    }else
    {
        file_frame = ("intro/00");
    }

    file_frame.append(ss.str());
    file_frame.append(".png");

    intro[i] = IMG_Load(file_frame.c_str());

}}
```

...

```
int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {

int frame = 0;

Timer fps;

init();

Player p1(0, player_1_colour, "player 1");

int frame_control = 0;

while(intro_control)
{
```

.....

PS: I suspect that there might be sth wrong with the "while(unit_file.eof()){" statement. But it's just a guess

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- Your while loop loops as long as eof is set (you should only loop until eof is set)
- Even if you fix the while loop, it would still be wrong because eof is only set AFTER you read beyond it, so you would have one invalid entry
- Why first get a line, only to put it in a string stream again and then parse it? You could just use the streaming operators of the file object directly.

I think the following would be a cleaner solution to your problem:

First, the Settler structure:

```
struct Settler {
  int type;     // Maybe some of those should be unsigned, 
                // but I just left them as you already had them
  int player;
  int x;
  int y;
  int health;
};
```

Then you can overload the >> operator for your class, to allow streaming it from any input stream. It takes the stream to read from as the first parameter and the object where the result should go as the second parameter:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream in&, Settler& settler) {
  // Just read the values in the corresponding fields of Settler
  return in >> settler.type 
     >> settler.player 
     >> settler.x 
     >> settler.y 
     >> settler.health;
}
```

Then you can read a whole file of settlers using a simple while loop:

```
int main() {
  std::ifstream file("test.txt");
  Settler current;
  std::vector<Settler> settlers;
  while(file >> current) { // Read as long as it's possible to 
                           // read a Settler
    settlers.push_back(current);
  };
}
```

There is a working example (which also overloads << for nice output, although in a real program on could overload << to produce the same format that >> reads in) at [ideone](http://ideone.com/isaf1O)

Comment: so I already have a Settler class but I add a settler struct in the main.cpp, right?

Comment: No, I just defined the Settler here because you didn't gave your class definition and I wanted to make this example a complete example. You can of course use your own Setter, but then you might have to change the operator>> overload.

Comment: Thank you very much,
Ill check it out and reply in a sec

Comment: Wait, what if I try to load different units (like sodier obj.) from the same file????

Comment: Maybe you should read a good book or tutorial (although good tutorials are not easy to find) to learn C++. C++ is not a good language for copy & pasting programs and also not for learning by doing, there are just too many pitfalls.

Comment: And right, i prefer Java much more that C++. Maybe because I started from JAva

Comment: one more question, I took out the settler.type part from the operator overload because settler doesnt have a value like this. Now, however how can I read other types of objects(all units will be saved in the same way. Only the first value will determine the type of the object to be created)

Comment: I did It my way just changing unit_file.eof() to !unit_file.eof()
It works but still thank you fr your help